# Children not rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on an app in React-Native and I am trying to render a component with children. If I use the component directly it functions 100% as expected, but if I return it from a conditional(switch) statement it doesn't render children. However the logic is functioning properly because I can actually see the state change.

I have it working 100% properly via conditional usage in another component, but it won't work in this particular case. It's imported correctly because the button renders, but without the child text inside of it, thus displaying just the button with no label text.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { LoginForm } from './components/LoginForm';
import { Header, Button, Spinner } from './components/common';

class App extends Component {
    state = { loggedIn: null };

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'nope',
            authDomain: 'nope',
            databaseURL: 'nope',
            projectId: 'nope',
            storageBucket: 'nope',
            messagingSenderId: 'nope'
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
        }
    });
}

    renderContent() {
        switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
            case true:
                return (
                  <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
                  Log Out
                  </Button>
                );
            case false:
                return <LoginForm />;
            default:
                return <Spinner size="large" />;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header headerText="Authentication" />
                {this.renderContent()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
    const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>
                {children}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const styles = {
    buttonStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#007aff',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5
    },
    textStyle: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: '#007aff',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10
    }
};

export { Button };
```

The state change is in fact working properly, as I can see the state change, but when the button is rendered it does not render the child text "Log Out".

If I use the Log Out directly in the main render method it displays fine, but when I call it via the renderContent() method it does not display the "Log Out" text.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in the button text as a prop instead of as a child.

```
renderContent() {
        switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
            case true:
                return <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()} btnText="Log Out" />;
            case false:
                return <LoginForm />;
            default:
                return <Spinner size="large" />;
        }
    }
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
    const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>
                {this.props.btnText}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const styles = {
    buttonStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#007aff',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5
    },
    textStyle: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: '#007aff',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10
    }
};

export { Button };
```

Comment: I've done exactly this and it still refuses to render the label.  It works 100% correctly elsewhere in the app, but in this particular instance it will not show the label text no matter what I do.